# How to parametrize Tensorflow Distributions?

Tags: tensorflow, distribution, tensorflow-probability

How can I parametrize Tensorflow Distributions? I.e. I want a Categorical distribution and want to add Gaussian Noise to it. tfp.distributions.Normal takes loc as an input, how can I set this loc to a Categorical distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Categorical has values in finite sets of integers, which won't really type check. If you have a set of mean locations and want to select them from a categorical you could do, eg

```
num_categories = 5
means = np.linspace(-10, 10, num_categories)
jd = tfd.JointDistributionSequential([
  tfd.Categorical(logits=tf.zeros([num_categories])),
  lambda c: tfd.Normal(loc=tf.gather(means, c), scale=1.)
])
```

(see [Modeling with JointDistributions](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Modeling_with_JointDistribution) for more on this style of model specification)

But this is equivalent to a [mixture of Gaussians](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/MixtureSameFamily?version=nightly):

```
msf = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    tfd.Categorical(logits=tf.zeros(num_categories])),
    tfd.Normal(loc=means, scale=1.))
```

You can also use [FiniteDiscrete](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/finite_discrete.py)* as a sort of real-valued
categorical.

Some further suggested reading for getting started:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/TensorFlow_Distributions_Tutorial
- https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Understanding_TensorFlow_Distributions_Shapes

* - for some reason FiniteDiscrete isn't being exported in our API docs. I'll look into fixing.